# comparing string with accents in php

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

I'm having problems when comparing two strings which contains accents.
This is my case:

**The first string is: Master** 
**The second string is: Máster Diseño Producción**

Then, I need to remove the word **Máster** from the second string, because it's contained in the first string.

I have created a function for clean each string:

```
function sanear_string($cadena)
{
    $cadena = trim($cadena);

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'ª', 'Á', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä'),
        array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë'),
        array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('í', 'ì', 'ï', 'î', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î'),
        array('i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ô'),
        array('o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ú', 'ù', 'ü', 'û', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü'),
        array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ñ', 'Ñ', 'ç', 'Ç'),
        array('n', 'N', 'c', 'C',),
        $cadena
    );

    //Esta parte se encarga de eliminar cualquier caracter extraño
    $cadena = str_replace(
        array("\\", "¨", "º", "-", "~",
            "#", "@", "|", "!", "\"",
            "·", "$", "%", "&", "/",
            "(", ")", "?", "'", "¡",
            "¿", "[", "^", "`", "]",
            "+", "}", "{", "¨", "´",
            ">", "<", ";", ",", ":",
            ".", " "),
        '',
        $cadena
    );


    return $cadena;
}
```

And it helps me to the problem of accents. Now I can use strpos to compare both strings...if result is > 0 then I know that the word is contained... but I need some help more....
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Some help doing what?

Comment: To finish my need...which is remove the word from the other string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual when dealing with charset problems, you need to be extra careful about the character counts between multibyte strings and plain ASCII strings.

Your biggest problem here is that you remove some pre-defined characters from the cleaned string, rendering character count coherence between the sanitized string and the original, thus greatly hardening the removal.

I'll use a modified version of your sanitizing function:

```
function sanitize($cadena) {
    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'ª', 'Á', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä'),
        array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë'),
        array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('í', 'ì', 'ï', 'î', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î'),
        array('i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ô'),
        array('o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ú', 'ù', 'ü', 'û', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü'),
        array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'),
        $cadena
    );

    $cadena = str_replace(
        array('ñ', 'Ñ', 'ç', 'Ç'),
        array('n', 'N', 'c', 'C',),
        $cadena
    );


    return strtolower($cadena);
}
```

The `remove_word` function follows:

```
function remove_word($haystack , $needle) {
    // sanitize input strings
    $haystack_san = sanitize($haystack);
    $needle_san = sanitize($needle);

    // Check for character loss
    if (mb_strlen($haystack_san, 'UTF-8') != mb_strlen($haystack, 'UTF-8') || mb_strlen($needle_san, 'UTF-8') != mb_strlen($needle, 'UTF-8')) {
        // Here for debugging purposes. You may want to drop it in production.
        echo "Lost some chars on the way. Aborting.\n";
        echo "     haystack: $haystack (".mb_strlen($haystack, "UTF-8").")\n";
        echo " haystack_san: $haystack_san (".mb_strlen($haystack_san, "UTF-8").")\n";
        echo "       needle: $needle (".mb_strlen($needle, "UTF-8").")\n";
        echo "   needle_san: $needle_san (".mb_strlen($needle_san, "UTF-8").")\n";
        return;
    }

    // Check if $needle is found in $haystack
    if (($pos = strpos($haystack_san, $needle_san)) !== false) {
        // Get the string before the word
        $new = mb_substr($haystack, 0, $pos, 'UTF-8');
        // If applicable, get the string after
        if (mb_strlen($haystack, 'UTF-8') - $pos - mb_strlen($needle, 'UTF-8') > 0)
            $new .= mb_substr($haystack, $pos + mb_strlen($needle), NULL, 'UTF-8');
        // Return it
        return $new;
    }

    // If the word wasn't found, return $haystack as-is
    return $haystack;
}

echo remove_word("Hola, Máster Diseño Producción", "Master");
// "Hola,  Diseño Producción"
```

Note that:

- This assumes your strings are UTF-8
- The code relies on `mb_*` function to handle multi-byte characters
- This only replaces the first occurence of the word (you may call `remove_word` until the string no longer changes if you want to replace all occurences)

Answer (score 1):

> if result is > 0 then I know that the word is contained

Not exactly. `strpos()` will return `0` if substring offset is zero, as in the case of strings: `'Master'` and `'Master Diseno Produccion'` (assuming your accents removal function works as expected). What you need is strict (`===`) comparison to `false`, e.g.:

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    // $needle exists in $haystack
} else {
    // no $needle in $haystack.
}
```

That said, if your goal is to remove the `$substr` from `$str`, use:

```
str_replace($substr, '', $str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at it based on the answer above (and including more characters);

```
/**
 * sanitize
 * 
 * @see     https://stackoverflow.com/a/23782573/115025
 * @access  public
 * @param   string $str
 * @return  string
 */
function sanitize(string $str): string
{
    $str = str_replace(
        array('à', 'á', 'â', 'ä', 'æ', 'ã', 'å', 'ā', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ä', 'Æ', 'Ã', 'Å', 'Ā'),
        array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ç', 'ć', 'č', 'Ç', 'Ć', 'Č'),
        array('c', 'c', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ē', 'ė', 'ę', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ē', 'Ė', 'Ę'),
        array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('î', 'ï', 'í', 'ī', 'į', 'ì', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Í', 'Ī', 'Į', 'Ì'),
        array('i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ł', 'Ł'),
        array('l', 'L'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ñ', 'ń', 'Ñ', 'Ń'),
        array('n', 'n', 'N', 'N'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ô', 'ö', 'ò', 'ó', 'œ', 'ø', 'ō', 'õ', 'Ô', 'Ö', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Œ', 'Ø', 'Ō', 'Õ'),
        array('o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ß', 'ś', 'š', 'Ś', 'Š'),
        array('ss', 's', 's', 'S', 'S'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('û', 'ü', 'ù', 'ú', 'ū', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Ū'),
        array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ÿ', 'Ÿ'),
        array('y', 'Y'),
        $str
    );
    $str = str_replace(
        array('ž', 'ź', 'ż', 'Ž', 'Ź', 'Ż'),
        array('z', 'z', 'z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
        $str
    );
    return strtolower($str);
}
```